# Climate change projections for Europe/Germany

Tags: geospatial, europe, germany, environment, climate

I am searching for climate projection data with the following criteria:

- covering Western/Central Europe (especially Germany), gridded data would be ideal
- monthly or at least seasonal (3-months) resolution
- temperature and precipitation
- covering the next 30-50 years
- from a reputable source (and OK to use for academic/scientific purpose)

Can you recommend a datasets that meets these criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking specifically for a small region in the European interior, you're going to need model simulations at the regional scale. For that I'd suggest checking out the CCAFS Downscaled Climate Change data portal: http://www.ccafs-climate.org/data/

The data offered there are 30-year monthly normalizations of most every AR4 and AR5 climate models and scenarios (SRESs and RCPs) for the 2030's, 2050's and 2070's. They also have the historical period data available at the same scales so you can perform present-day comparisons with future periods to identify climate anomalies and areas where changes may be more drastic. The license agreement allows academic/non-commercial use as well.

You can download realizations by tile but be warned that the data storage needed is considerable, especially if you want to calculate model ensemble averages. If you're going that route, you might want to consider only using the models with the highest validation statistics representing each cluster. For more info: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/grl.50256/abstract